# Essential singularity mapping to $\mathbb{C}$ proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0$ be an essential singularity of $f$ and let $U$ be any deleted neighborhood of $z_0$. Prove that the closure of $f(U)$ is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Time to learn to typeset the math.

Comment: thanks for bumping the question for me :)

Comment: [Casorati-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

It's Casorati-Weierstrass theorem. Proof is straightforward: assume $f$ on $U_Z$ misses a ball around $a$, then $\frac 1 {f - a}$ is holomorphic and bounded on some $U_Z' \subset U_Z$. Expressing $f$ through this function you see that singularity was actually removable or a pole, contradiction.